# PHP array_unique is converted to object

Tags: php, arrays

Here is a dummy example:

```
$errors = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $errors[] = [
        'id' => $i
    ];
}

$errors[] = [
    'id' => 0
];

for ($i = 3; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $errors[] = [
        'id' => $i
    ];
}


var_dump($errors);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump(array_unique($errors, SORT_REGULAR));
```

The output above is:

```
array(6) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(0) } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(1) } 
    [2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } 
    [3]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(0) } 
    [4]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(3) } 
    [5]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(4) } 
} 

array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(0) } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(1) } 
    [2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } 
    [4]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(3) } 
    [5]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(4) } 
}
```

As you can see, the second case, the index `3` is missing. So when I return this through an API, it is returned as an object with keys,  `0,1,2,4,5`.

Comment: `array_unique()` does **not** convert your array into an object.

Comment: it doesn't convert it into an object, it turns it into an associated array

Comment: Okay, but I then return this item through an API interface, and Javascript receives it as an object.

Comment: Are you doing anything like `json_encode()` when you return the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `array_unique()` filters out equal values so the reason why #3 of the index is missing is because its equal to #0.

You can re-index the array with `array_values()`:

```
var_dump(array_values(array_unique($errors, SORT_REGULAR)));
```

JavaScript perceives PHP's *associative array's* as an object because it only understands *numeric keyed* arrays.

You should be using [json](/questions/tagged/json) to communicate between both languages:

```
echo json_encode($errors);
```

As this would cause in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) the outer the value to be turned into an array and turn each item into an object.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(outputofjson_encode);

console.log(arr[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `array_values`:

```
$errors = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $errors[] = [
        'id' => $i
    ];
}

$errors[] = [
    'id' => 0
];

for ($i = 3; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $errors[] = [
        'id' => $i
    ];
}

$errors = array_values(array_unique($errors, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: Cause I did not see your response! I marked yours as a the solution